# Sort start/end dates of ban chronologically not alphanumerically in review ban tool

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

It's currently possible to click the table headers on /admin/review/ban to sort by column which is a nice touch. However, for the start and end dates it's not particularly useful - see the following dates in (supposed) order of expiry...

[image]

It's no biggy, but it'd be nice to have and I'm hoping it's a simple change such as adjusting the script to pick up the tooltip text (formatted timestamp text) instead of the cell contents.

Comment: You have that many users review-banned *at one time*? Wow, SO does have crazy stats. Some sites would be lucky to get that many people doing anything in the review queues in a month!